# Tables goes unwantedly on next page using IEEE journal

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx, subfloats, ieeetran

I have made a table with two subtables, that go in to the margin on the sides. For some reason the table always go on the next page even though using `[h]` or `[!b]`. An example:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\restylefloat{table}


\title{
Title}
\author{Author}
\date{April 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}
\section{Introduktion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean viverra sed nibh in vestibulum.
Mauris tincidunt elit arcu, non dignissim enim blandit at. Morbi efficitur, nisl a vehicula 
iaculis, odio nibh pharetra magna, at lacinia diam erat ac libero. Aliquam aliquam interdum
 bibendum. Etiam sodales ante magna, id suscipit nisi posuere in. Suspendisse quis efficitur dui.
 Donec est metus, scelerisque non fermentum nec, elementum at lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
 in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Fusce lorem nisl, posuere sit amet
 augue eget, feugiat lobortis lectus. Maecenas aliquet rhoncus nisl quis fermentum. Donec
 condimentum semper risus, id egestas tortor semper sit amet.

\begin{table*}[!b]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \makebox[7cm]{\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5cm}llllll@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{}{} Parameter &  $n$ & $\bar{x}$ & $s$ & Min & Max & CI($95 \%$)\\
    \midrule
     $k_{cp}$ & 10 & 0.1546& 0.0387 & 0.0915 & 0.2056 & \\
     $k_{pc}$ &   10 & 0.0425 & 0.0038 & 0.0339& 0.0473 & \\ $k_{ce}$ & 10 & 0.0425  & 0.0038 & 0.0339 & 0.0473 & \\
     $k_{a} $ & 10 & 0.4985 & 0.0045 & 0.4856 & 0.5000 & \\
     $F$  & 10 & 3.654 & 2.186 & 1.756 & 8.479 & $[2.091, 5.218]$\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}}%
    \makebox[14.5cm]{\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{1cm}lllll@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{}{} Parameter &  $n$ & $\bar{x}$ & $s$ & Min & Max\\
    \midrule
     $K_{el}$ & 10 & 0.4985 & 0.0045 & 0.4856 & 0.500\\
     $AUC$ & 10 & 61.02 & 43.33 & 28.26 & 168.6\\ 
     $CL$ & 10 & 0.0621  & 0.0064 & 0.0503 & 0.0729\\
     $MRT$ & 10 & $2.039\cdot10^3$ & $1.527\cdot10^3$ & 964.0 & $5.904\cdot10^3$\\
     $V_{ss}$ & 10 & 121.7 & 76.41 & 59.89 & 296.9\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}} 
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The table output, that goes on the next page:

[image]

Comment: `table*` does not have an `h` option, and always comes on the next page at the earliest

Comment: You can try `\usepackage{stfloats}` and see if that helps. But this seems to be in part a deliberate decision by the makers of IEEEtrans.cls; see [the documentation](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) page 9.

Comment: @frabjous This seems to actually have worked!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a good reason for placing the subtables in a `table*` environment to begin with. Placing them in an ordinary `table` environment would appear to be just fine (if not better), especially if one employs `tabular*` instead of `tabular` environments to assure that the (sub)tables span the full width of the column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the LaTeX default nowadays
\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{subcaption}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{April 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduktion}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Global caption}
    
    \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}
    \caption{}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{l} @{}}
    \toprule
    Param. & $n$ & $\bar{x}$ & $s$ & Min & Max & CI ($95\%$)\\
    \midrule
     $k_{cp}$ & 10 & 0.1546 & 0.0387 & 0.0915 & 0.2056 & \\
     $k_{pc}$ & 10 & 0.0425 & 0.0038 & 0.0339 & 0.0473 & \\ 
     $k_{ce}$ & 10 & 0.0425 & 0.0038 & 0.0339 & 0.0473 & \\
     $k_{a} $ & 10 & 0.4985 & 0.0045 & 0.4856 & 0.5000 & \\
     $F$      & 10 & 3.654  & 2.186  & 1.756  & 8.479  & $[2.091, 5.218]$\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \end{subtable}
  
  \bigskip
  \begin{subtable}{\columnwidth}
  \caption{}
  \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{l} @{}}
     \toprule
     Param. & $n$ & $\bar{x}$ & $s$ & Min & Max\\
     \midrule
     $K_{el}$ & 10 & 0.4985 & 0.0045 & 0.4856 & 0.500\\
     $\mathrm{AUC}$ & 10 & 61.02 & 43.33 & 28.26 & 168.6\\ 
     $\mathrm{CL}$ & 10 & 0.0621  & 0.0064 & 0.0503 & 0.0729\\
     $\mathrm{MRT}$ & 10 & $2.039\cdot10^3$ & $1.527\cdot10^3$ & 964.0 & $5.904\cdot10^3$\\
     $V_{ss}$ & 10 & 121.7 & 76.41 & 59.89 & 296.9\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \end{subtable} 
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```